# Program for finding min, max, average, median and mode

Tags: c++, max, min, mode, median

#### Background

Write a C++ program that takes a user input of a set of numbers, and outputs the maximum value, minimum value, average, median, and mode. We know that the mode can be more than one number so write your code so it outputs multiple modes if necessary.

#### Sample Input

Enter integers and enter a letter when done.

```
-2 3 3 5 6 4 4 8 9 9 9 1 -2 10 10 10
```

#### Sample Output

```
Your numbers are: -2 -2 1 3 3 4 4 5 6 8 9 9 9 10 10 10
Max: 10  
Min: -2  
Average: 5.4375  
Median: 5.5  
Mode: 9 10 (3)
```

#### My Code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    double value, sum;
    double average, minimum, maximum;
    int count;
    // initialise
    sum = 0.0;
    count = 0;
    cout << "Enter a value: ";
    cin >> value;
    minimum = value;
    maximum = value;
    while (value >= 0.0)
    {
        // process value
        sum += value;
        count++;
        if (value > maximum)
            maximum = value;
        else if (value < minimum)
            minimum = value;
        // get next value
        cout << "Enter a value: ";
        cin >> value;
    }
    if (count == 0)
        cout << "No data entry" << endl;
    else
    {
        average = sum / count;
        cout << "There were " << count << " numbers" << endl;
        cout << "Average was " << average << endl;
        cout << "Minimum was " << minimum << endl;
        cout << "Maximum was " << maximum << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried something or gave us to do your homework?

Comment: I've tried something, this is my code so far, it wont let me paste it because its too long

Comment: You need to do more than include your code _in your post_. You need to tell more than what your assignment is. Things like what exactly you're having problems with, compiler or linker errors, if the program runs what output are you getting and why is it wrong.

Comment: cant figure out how to calculate the median and mode

Comment: how would the process terminate? your current code's max-min is not working for the given input.

Comment: `while (value >= 0.0)` won't let you enter negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use STL, you can write something like this (use c++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
template<typename A, typename B>
std::pair<B,A> flip_pair(const std::pair<A,B> &p)
{
    return std::pair<B,A>(p.second, p.first);
}
template<typename A, typename B>
std::multimap<B,A> flip_map(const std::map<A,B> &src)
{
    std::multimap<B,A> dst;
    std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), std::inserter(dst, dst.begin()), 
                   flip_pair<A,B>);
    return dst;
}
int main() {
  std::string line;
  std::cout << "Enter numbers: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, line);
  std::istringstream iss(line);
  std::vector<int> elements;
  elements.reserve(1000);
  std::string elem;
  while (std::getline(iss, elem, ' ')) {
    try {
      elements.push_back(std::stoi(elem));
    } catch (...) {  }
  }
  double sum = 0.0;
  std::size_t n = elements.size();
  std::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end());
  std::cout << "max=" << elements.back() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "min=" << elements.front() << std::endl;
  for (auto &x: elements) {
    sum += x;
  }
  if (n == 0) return 1;
  std::cout << "avg=" << sum / n << std::endl;
  if (n == 1) {
    std::cout << "med=" << elements[0] << std::endl;
  }
  else if (n % 2 == 0) {
    std::size_t i = n/2;
    std::cout << "med=" << (double)(elements[i] + elements[i-1]) / 2.0 << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "med=" << elements[n/2] << std::endl;
  }
  std::set<int> elements_set;
  for (auto &x: elements) {
    elements_set.insert(x);
  }
  std::map<int, std::size_t> elements_count;
  for (auto &x: elements_set) {
    elements_count.insert(std::pair<int, std::size_t>(x, std::count(elements.begin(), elements.end(), x)));
  }
  std::multimap<std::size_t, int> count_elements;
  count_elements = flip_map(elements_count);
  std::cout << "mod: ";
  std::size_t count_mod = count_elements.rbegin()->first;
  for (auto &x: count_elements) {
    if (x.first == count_mod) {
      std::cout << x.second << ", ";
    }
    else {  }
  }
  std::cout << "(" << count_mod << ")" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is an edited version of your code which is fully working:

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        double value, sum;
        double average, minimum=(double)INFINITY, maximum=-(double)INFINITY, median;
        map<int,int>modes;
        vector<int>data;
        int count,mxmode=0;
        // initialise
        sum = 0.0;
        count = 0;
        cout << "Enter a value (To end, press Ctrl+Z and Enter): ";

        while (cin >> value)
        {
            // process value
            sum += value;
            count++;
            if (value > maximum)
                maximum = value;

            if (value < minimum)
                minimum = value;

            modes[ value ]++;
            mxmode = max(mxmode, modes[value]);
            data.push_back(value);

            // get next value
            cout << "Enter a value (To end, press Ctrl+Z and Enter): ";
        }
        if (count == 0)
            cout << "No data entry" << endl;
        else
        {
            average = sum / count;

            sort(data.begin(), data.end());

            if(data.size()%2==0) median = ( data[ data.size()/2 - 1 ] + data[ data.size()/2 ] )/2.0;
            else median = data[ data.size()/2 ];

            cout << "There were " << count << " numbers" << endl;
            cout << "Average was " << average << endl;
            cout << "Minimum was " << minimum << endl;
            cout << "Maximum was " << maximum << endl;
            cout << "Median was " << median << endl;
            cout << "Mode was";

            for (auto &x: modes)
                if(x.second == mxmode) cout<<" "<<x.first;

            cout<<" ("<<mxmode<<")" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Remember:

- Don't forget to compile it with the most recent `-std=c++11` flag as I used the feature of C++11.
- Input is terminated by `EOF` or in console you can terminate it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Use corresponding keys if you are in different OS than Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Median:

First, you need to sort your numbers. You can store them in an array and then use a sorting algorithm e.g. insertion sort, selection sort etc. Once the array is sorted, the median is the middle number. Below, there is the the code for insertion sort implementation assuming that you have stored your numbers in `arr[]` and `length` is the length of your array.

```
    void insertion_sort(double arr[], int length) {
      int i, j;
      double tmp; 
      for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
          tmp = arr[j];
          arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
          arr[j - 1] = tmp;
          j--;
        }//end of while loop
        print_array(arr,5);
      }//end of for loop
    }//end of insertion_sort.
```

Mode:

You can have a counter to keep track of every number in your array. The most frequent one is the mode.

Comment: You have the sorting complexity of O(n^2), so why are you not using built-in sort?

Comment: That's right! But, the question was not about complexity. I just gave an example, you can use any sorting you want.

Comment: If no matter of complexity, then why are you using complex code for a newbie?